# how can I color space between lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to draw some square tiles on wall in illustrator  , so i must create grid on wall , Is creating grid by line segment tool correct?
how to color squares created between lines? 
here is a picture of my problem
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw your grid flat and create a pattern.

- Create a rectangle
- Choose `Object > Path > Split Into Grid...` To define the number of sections.
- Fill your sections with whatever colors you want
- Select the entire grid and drag it to the **Swatch Panel** to create a pattern.
- Draw another rectangle which will be your wall (just draw a straight rectangle)
- Fill the new rectangle with your new pattern
- Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh`
- Enter 1 row and 1 column for the mesh and hit OK.
- Select the **Free Transform Tool**
- Click a corner handle **THEN** hold down the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys and drag to create the perspective appearance.
- Move your new pattern filled wall into place.

[image]

Adding the Envelope mesh allows the pattern to distort along with the encompassing rectangle. Without the envelope you'll get a distorted rectangle but the pattern within will still be square and flat.

Note: You could also use the perspective grid rather than the Free Transform Tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your lines into a LivePaint object and use the LivePaint fill tool to color them.